# Como verificar se o valor de variável string é numero?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Eu estou desenvolvendo um programa onde o usuário digita um dado, em seguida tenho que verificar se o valor é número para prosseguir com a operação, mas caso ele digite um valor não numérico ele seja alertado sobre o valor invalido.

Tentei usar a função `type()` mas ela verifica o tipo de variável e não o valor dela, então fica difícil dado o fato que a função `input()` retorna a entra como *string*.

```
case = input(escolha um valor de 0 a 10)
if type(case) != int:
   print("Digite apenas numeros!")
else:
   #--processo
```

Eu pensei em formata o `input()` com `int()` mas caso o usuário digitasse um caractere não numérico o programa apresentará erro, quando na verdade eu gostaria de tratar isso pedindo a ela para digitar apenas números.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/528526/112052

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As strings em Python tem um método "isdigit": `case.isdigit()`  - que retorna True ou False.

Esse método é o suficiente se você quer só inteiros positivos - no entanto, se desejar validar também entrada de números com ponto decimal ou negativos, o melhor é fazer uma função que tenta converter o número dentro de um `try...except`  e chamar essa função para verificar. Aí com o minimo de codigo, você passa a aceitar todas as variantes de sintaxe para números (negativo, em notação  exponencial, infinito, etc...):

```
def isnumber(value):
    try:
         float(value)
    except ValueError:
         return False
    return True

...

if isnumber(case):
    ...
```

Esse método tem o seguinte efeito colateral que por vezes pode ser desejável, mas as vezes não: ele valida todas as formas possíveis de representação de um float em Python - não só a presença de sinal e ponto decimal, mas também notação científica e os valores especiais "NaN" (not a number), "inifinity" (infinidade ou infinito) e a notação científica - que permite a especificação da posição do ponto decimal com o prefixo "e":

```
>>> [float(exemplo) for exemplo in ("infinity", "NaN", "1.23e-4")]                                              
[inf, nan, 0.000123]
```

Se isso não for desejado, uma função que faça as duas validações pode ser melhor - primeiro detecta os caracteres - e depois usa a conversão pra `float` pra não se preocupar se o número é válido (isso é: só um ponto decimal, o sinal é o primeiro caractere, etc...):

```
def is_simple_number(value):
    if not value.strip().replace('-', '').replace('+', '').replace('.', '').isdigit():
        return False
    try:
         float(value)
    except ValueError:
         return False
    return True
```

As strings em Python também tem os métodos `isnumeric` e  `isdecimal` - mas elas são sinônimos do `isdigit` - nenhum dos dois métodos aceita ponto decimal ou sinal, por exemplo.

Answer (score 13):

Pode usar [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

```
num = input("escolha um valor de 0 a 10")
if not num.isdigit():
    print("Digite apenas numeros!")
print(num)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/SjOLLf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hnizohpf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/Isdigit.py).

Eu acho uma gambiarra de usar exceção para tratar disto. Há um enorme abuso em todas linguagens. Exceção é útil, mas hoje quase todo uso acaba sendo um erro no mínimo conceitual. Embora talvez em Python considerem aceitável por falta de um mecanismo melhor.

Se deseja algo além disto seria interessante criar um função que trate com o critério que precisa. E se precisar de performance talvez compense fazer em C e integrar com Python.

Comment: Excelente a explicação de que deve-se evitar Exceptions. No meu ver é por questão de performance. Há mais algum bom motivo?

Comment: Porque em geral não há uma situação excepcional ali, é um conceito errado, quando se conceitua errado tudo vai descarrilando. Se pesquisar sobre tem muita informação, aqui mesmo tem uma quantidade enorme de respostas minhas sobre.

Answer (score 6):

Verificar se é int:

```
def isInt(value):
  try:
    int(value)
    return True
  except:
    return False
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: não é legal usar 'except"  sem especificar a exceção gerada - no caso ValueError. Em Python 3 isso é inclusive um erro de sintaxe - mas o problema é que se acontecer algum outro tipo de erro no trecho do try, vocẽ vai ter um rpoblema no código que vai ser bem difícil de localizar.

Answer (score 6):

Tente convertê-lo em um int

```
 try:
   val = int(userInput)
 except ValueError:
   print("Não é número")
```

fonte  [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Answer (score 6):

Senti falta de uma resposta com expressão regular. Para padrões inteiros:

```
import re # pacote com as rotinas de expressão regular
pattern_int = re.compile(r"(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)")

entrada = input()
if pattern_int.match(entrada):
    print(entrada + " é um número inteiro")
else:
    print(entrada + " não é um número inteiro")
```

Veja [funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/oIzr2z).

Answer (score 0):

```
def henum(num):
    numeros= ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    for digito in num:
        if digito in numeros:
            return True
        else:
            return False

num = input("Digite um número: ")
if henum(num):
    print("é numero!!!")
else:
     print("Não é numero!!!")
```

Comment: E qual a diferença de fazer assim para o `num.isdigit()`, como citado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210021/5878)?

Comment: Sua solução está absolutamente correta, apenas quis ilustrar, utilizando outra maneira de abordar o problema.
Costumo demonstrar aos meus alunos como algumas funções ou métodos realizam os procedimentos, para que os mesmos possam entender a lógica.
Abraços.

Comment: você pode editar a resposta, e colocar esse comentário que contextualiza  o seu código e explica sua motivação no começo da mesma.

Comment: Então sugiro que edite sua resposta e explique, de fato, alguma coisa. Até então você só respondeu com um código avulso que pode não fazer sentido para muitos usuários da comunidade.

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é utilizando **[Assignment Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)**, abordados pela **[PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)**. Com esta técnica o código ficaria:

```
while not (n := input('Valor entre 0 e 10: ')).isdigit() or (n := int(n)) < 0 or n > 10:
    print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

print(n)
```

Quando executamos este código é verificado três condições:

1. Verifica se o que foi digitado NÃO é um dígito;
2. Verifica se a string convertida em inteiro é menor que "0";
3. Verifica se a string convertida em inteiro é maior que "10".

Caso, **uma** destas três condições seja **True**, receberemos a mensagem:

```
Valor INVÁLIDO!
```

E caso **todas** as três condições sejam **False**, o laço de repetição é finalizado.

Para deixar o código mais entendível resolvi exibir o valor digitado, caso as três verificações sejam **False**.

Caso, as três verificações sejam **False**, significa dizer que **o valor digitado é um número e está entre 0 e 10, incluindo o 0 e o 10**.

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite, sou novato no Python e aqui também, mas consegui resolver desta forma para ponto flutuante:

```
str(price).replace('.','').isnumeric()
```

creio que desta forma seja mais simples, espero que ajude

Answer (score -2):

Estou iniciando no Python a algumas semanas.
No exemplo que eu estava estudando "TUPLAS" ela não tem as funções colocadas acima que começam com "`is`" (como `isInt()`, `isdigit()`, etc...).

Então com o `try` resolvi tranquilamente. Segue meu exemplo abaixo.

```
def soma_todos_numeros(*args):

    try:

        return sum(args)

    except:

        return False


print(soma_todos_numeros('a'))

print(soma_todos_numeros(1))

print(soma_todos_numeros(2,3))

print(soma_todos_numeros(2,3,4))

print(soma_todos_numeros(3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: Verifique a versão do seu interpretador Python pois nos interpretadores Python  atualizados você encontrará a disponibilidade os métodos: [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric), [`str.isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal), [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)

Answer (score -3):

```
def Verificar_tipo(num):
    try:
        num / 2

    except TypeError:
        print("Não é um numero")
        return exit()

    else:
        exit()


Verificar_tipo('Número')
```

Comment: Não é um teste confiável, dado que `num` pode ser instância de um tipo que sobrecarrega o operador `/`. Por exemplo, uma instância de `pathlib.Path` possui o operador `/` e seria *tratado* como um número.

Answer (score -5):

Use o método de verificação que já vem no Python, o `is`. Veja abaixo seu código retificado:

```
case = input(escolha um valor de 0 a 10)  
verificação = isnumeric(case)  

if verificação == True:  
    print ('O número digitado foi {}'.format(case))  
elif verificação == False:  
    print ('Digite apenas numeros!')
```

O `isnumeric` verifica se na variável que você criou `case` foi adicionado apenas números, caso tenha algo além de números (letras ou espaços) ele retorna o resultado negativo `False`. Eu atribui o resultado da verificação à uma nova variável que chamei de `verificação` e fiz os blocos condicionais atrelados à ela. Se `verificação` for True, ou seja, tiver apenas números, exiba o número digitado, se for False, exiba `"Digite apenas numeros!"`.

PS: Lembra de indentar o `print` para dentro da condição, não consegui escrever aqui nesse editor os espaços à esquerda do `print`.

Comment: Votei negativo basicamente porque nem é um código Python válido. 1) Faltam as aspas na função `input`; 2) A função `isnumeric` não existe - talvez tenha desejado se referir à `str.isnumeric`; 3) Não tem poque fazer `verificação == True`, apenas `if verificação` bastaria; 4) `elif` para verificar se é falso? Ou é verdadeiro ou falso, se não é verdadeiro será falso, não precisa verificar novamente; pode usar o `else`.

Comment: Quanto à formatação do código, leia o [guia de formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).