# Python - filtrando dados em arquivos de texto

Tags: python, filtro, texto

Estou tentando escrever um código para ler um arquivo .txt e extrair coordenadas numéricas, só que este arquivo contém linhas com textos também. Não estou conseguindo fazer o filtro. veja uma parte do arquivo.

[image: imagem do arquivo txt]
Até agora eu consegui escrever o seguinte:

```
filename = 'arquivo.txt'
with open(file_name) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
values = line.split()
```

agora eu tento filtrar somente os valores das coordenadas das linhas 236, 244, 250, 256... poderia usar o valor da primeira coluna para filtrar pois é padrão, por exemplo: 110 na linha 236 e 105, 100, 35 das demais linhas.
Como são coordenadas x y z o próximo passo seria subtrair a quinta coluna da segunda - a sexta da terceira - e a sétima da quarta.

Comment: Blz, mas faltou explicar a sua dúvida, onde precisa de ajuda, o que não conseguiu fazer e tem dúvida. Tente colocar entrada e saída esperada, isso ajuda muito. Se quiser filtrar só os valores das coordenadas nas linhas 236, 244, 250 e 256 é bem simples. Mas imagino q não seja isso

Answer (score 2):

Para filtrar esses valores observe os padrões do seu arquivo, uma rápida olhada me deu alguns padrões que parecem satisfazer suas necessidades, a primeira coluna deve ser sempre `maior que zero` e os valores contidos entre a coluna `dois até a nove` não deve possuir `zero`, podemos então multiplicar todos os valores da coluna dois até a nona, se o resultado for maior que zero a linha vai satisfazer suas necessidades, se essas duas condições forem atendidas guarde a linha inteira para posterior uso, segue código contendo a lógica explicada acima:

```
filename = 'arquivo.txt'

resultado=[]

with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    values = line.split()

    try:
        inteiros = map(int, values[0:9])

    except ValueError:
        continue

    try:

        if inteiros[0] > 0:
            multiplica = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, inteiros[1:8])
            if multiplica > 0:
                resultado.append(values)


    except:
        continue

print resultado
```

Ajudaria muito se você tivesse colocado junto a sua pergunta o arquivo de entrada ao invés de colocar somente a imagem dela...

Comment: Sobre as exceções esperadas, acho que esse outro [comentário do @jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210010/como-verificar-se-o-valor-de-vari%c3%a1vel-string-%c3%a9-numero/210012#comment429365_210012) é relevante para sua resposta

Comment: no meu código observe a linha `map(int, values[0:9])` ele converte pra inteiro

Comment: Sim, o problema é só o `expect` vazio, que em Python 3 seria erro de sintaxe

Comment: não tenho como testar no `python3`, só tenho o `python27` and run like a charm lol, quer dizer que `python3` não deixaria o meu `except` seguido de um `continue` passar?

Comment: Sim. Creio que `expect ValueError` resolveria tudo

Comment: http://ideone.com/, tem interpretador para Python3

Comment: humm também funfou no `python27`, interessante huahua, coloquei pra deixar o mais usável possível para ambas as versões...