# Verificar se valor é string ou número

Tags: python, python-3.x

**10) Faça um algoritmo que verifica se um determinado valor é uma String.**

```
valor = str(input("Informe um valor: "))

if(type(valor) == str):
    print("É uma String!")
```

No IDLE ou no Python Console do PyCharm, se digito:

```
valor = "João"
type(valor)
```

ele retorna:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Pesquisei no Google e ouvi sobre uma função **isinstance()**

**11) Faça um algoritmo que verifica se um determinado valor é do tipo decimal.**

```
valor = input("Informe um valor: ")

if(isinstance(valor, float)):
    print("É um decimal!")
else:
    print("Não é um decimal!")
```

O código acima, da pergunta 11, resulta numa saída errada, pois se eu digito 3, ou 3.2, em ambos ele retorna "Não é um decimal!"

Gostaria de saber as respostas pra essas 2 perguntas..(uso Python 2.7 ou Python 3.7, ambas estão em Ambientes Virtuais com Anaconda)

Consegui fazer 14 exercícios de 18, porém estes 2 e mais outros 2 que talvez eu poste posteriormente, não consegui.

Comment: `input` [sempre retorna uma string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). Para verificar se esta string contém um valor que representa um número, aí vc usa algo assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210010/112052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Considerando apenas o sistema decimal (sem levar em conta hexa, octal, etc):

```
valor='1'
while valor!='0':
    valor = input('Digite o valor:')
    try:
        print(float(valor),' É um numero')
    except ValueError:
        print(valor, 'É uma string')
```

**Obs.:**
Com um pouco de esforço vc pode refinar mais para distinguir inteiros de float.

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/string-or-number?language=python3)

Answer (score 1):

> O código acima, da pergunta 11, resulta numa saída errada, pois se eu digito 3, ou 3.2, em ambos ele retorna "Não é um decimal!"

O código retrata o que está acontecendo - o valor de retorno do `input` em Python 3 *sempre* é uma string.

Para verificar se a string pode ser usada como um inteiro ou um número decimal, você tem que escrever mais código. Por exemplo, strings tem o método `.isdigit()` que retorna True se todos os caractéres na string são dígitos - isso permite verificar se a string contém um inteiro.

Você pode usar também o método `.count` e verificar se a contagem do carácter "." (ou ",", como preferir) dentro da string é 1. A forma mais prática de verificar se é um número float válido no entanto é tentar converte-la pra float, e capturar um eventual erro, com um try/except - se der erro, é por que não é um float válido.

```
a = input("digite coisas:")
try:
   b = float(a)
except ValueError:
   eh_decimal = False
else:
   eh_decimal = True

...
```

Talvez você tenha se confundido com algum exemplo que tenha visto de Python 2, o `input` tenta interpretar o que for digitado como se fosse uma expressão de Python. Então números são retornados diretamente do input como "int" e "float" (e texto, em geral vai dar um erro ) . Em Python 2, o correto era usar  `raw_input` no lugar do input.

Comment: Caramba... Essa parte do codigo ja existia qdo dei minha resposta? Se sim realmente to ficando pirado. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso

```
valor = "Joao"
if type(valor) is str:
    print("é string")
```

Comment: Olá @deshPro. Tente detalhar mais a sua resposta. Talvez explicar resumidamente o que faz a sua solução.