# Python verificando se o numero é Float

Tags: python, float

Sou bem iniciante na programação python, minha duvida é o seguinte, preciso que o usuário digite apenas numero float, como eu faço essa verificação e informo o erro caso não seja? só consegui fazer se o numero for inteiro, mas float estou com dificuldades.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210010/112052

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como verificar se o valor de variável string é numero?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210010/como-verificar-se-o-valor-de-vari%c3%a1vel-string-%c3%a9-numero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor forma de testar é usando o método `isinstance(valor, tipo)`

Exemplo:

```
valor = 13.3

if isinstance(valor, float):
   print("é float")
else:
    print("não é float")
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é colocar o usuário em um loop até que a entrada seja possível de ser representada como um valor do tipo float.

Segue um exemplo:

```
def lerNumeroFloat():
    while True:
        try:
            numero = input("Digite um número: ")
            decimalNumber = float(numero)
            return decimalNumber
        except:
            print("Não é float. Tente novamente")

lerNumeroFloat()
```