# Por que quando deixo o campo ano_nasc vazio o programa dá erro e para? Quero que ele informe o erro e continue perguntando até o valor ser preenchido

Tags: python

```
def calcula_idade():

    while True:

        nome = str(input("Digite seu nome completo:"))

        if nome == '':
            print("Não pode deixar o campo nome em branco.")
            continue
        elif nome.isnumeric():
            print("Digite apenas letras.")
            continue

        ano_nasc = int(input("Digite seu ano de nascimento:"))

        if ano_nasc == '':
            print("Idade não pode ficar em branco.")
            continue
        elif ano_nasc == str:
            print("Idade inválida.")
            continue
        elif ano_nasc < 1922 or ano_nasc >= 2022:
            print("Digite uma idade válida.")
            continue
        else:
            idade_atual = 2022 - ano_nasc
            print(f"Seu nome é {nome} e em 2022 você completará {idade_atual} anos.")
            break


calcula_idade()
```

Comment: `int(algo)` tenta converter `algo` para número. Se vc não digitar nada, `input` retorna uma string vazia, que não pode ser convertida para número, por isso dá erro (e as verificações não fazem sentido: como `int` retorna um número, as condições do primeiro e segundo `if` nunca serão verdadeiras). Para validar se foi digitado um número, veja aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/210010/112052

Comment: Brigadão Augusto, vou dá uma lida aqui, vlw msm.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Quando você cria uma variável do tipo *string* e não estabelece um valor, o python aceita. Ex: a = ''
   Que é exatamente o que acontece quando você chama a variável nome e o usuário não insere valor algum. Porém isso não é permitido para variáveis do tipo *integrais* (INT). Quando você chama a variável ano_nasc e condiciona essa variável para ser do tipo *INT* (integral), você recebe um ValueError, ou seja, um erro de valor.
2. Uma solução que me ocorreu é primeiro checar se a linha está em branco e só depois converter o valor para uma integral. Então, ao invés de você escrever:

   ```
   ano_nasc = int(input("Digite seu ano de nascimento:"))
   ```

você poderia colocar assim:

```
ano_nasc = input("Digite seu ano de nascimento:")
if len(ano_nasc) > 0:
    ano_nasc = int(ano_nasc)
```

Nesse caso o valor recebido na variável ano_nasc vai ser do tipo string e, se o tamanho for maior que zero, ou seja, houver algum valor, ela depois vai converter para uma integral.

Comment: Texto do AR: *Não é uma solução perfeita, certamente algum usuário mais experiente pode pensar em uma solução mais eficiente e simples, mas ta aí minha contribuição.*

Comment: blz, valeu mesmo.